# unknown table 'user' in field list

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

Here's my code, i am getting the error message "unknown table 'user' in field list"
How do i fix this?

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
Dim mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection
Dim command As MySqlCommand
Dim query As String = ""
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader


Private Sub loginbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loginbutton.Click
    getdbdata()
End Sub

Private Sub getdbdata()

    Try
        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;username=root;database=bank")

        query = "select user.Username, user.Password, user.Email" & _
                "from user"

        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        mysqlconn.Open()

        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        While reader.Read
            txtusername.Text = txtusername.Text & reader.Item("Username") & vbCrLf
            txtpassword.Text = txtpassword.Text & reader.Item("Password") & vbCrLf
            txtemail.Text = txtemail.Text & reader.Item("Email")
        End While

        reader.Close()
        mysqlconn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: `User` is a reserved word in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Is the table "User" in the "Bank" database? If so try this:

```
query = "select Username, Password, Email " & _
"from [user]"
```

Comment: user is a table in bank database. when i edited the code there's an error message that says "there's an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: Missing space between Email and From.